# Javascript bitwise operation gives different result in python

Tags: javascript, python

My javascript code gives 5322244621 but my python code gives me 22502113805

Python:
`x = (144366253 << 7 | 144366253 >> 32 - 7) + 4023233417`

Javascript:
`var x = (144366253 << 7) | (144366253 >> (32 - 7)) + 4023233417;`

Im expecting the python code to return the same as the javascript code

Comment: Well for starters, those are different expressions. Python will give you a different answer for each one.

Comment: Can you reduce those expressions to a [mre]? There seems to be excess complication that just makes it harder to understand your question. For example, is the `+ 4023233417` really necessary to reproduce this behavior? Do the numbers have to be `144366253`, or do simpler values work the same?

Comment: Javascript: `(144366253n << 7n | 144366253n >> 32n - 7n) + 4023233417n`. The resulting number in your code is too large to be represented in the `number` primitive so you have to use `BigInt`. The above expression should give you the same as `(144366253 << 7 | 144366253 >> 32 - 7) + 4023233417` in Python.

Comment: Immediate culprit that comes to mind is JS having 2 right shift operators: `>>` and `>>>`. `>>>` is the one that works same as Python's `>>`.

Comment: It seems that Javascript ints can overflow and "wrap around". So for example `144366253 << 3` gives the same result in JS and Python, but `144366253 << 4`  gives `2309860048` in Python but it overflows in JS and returns `-1985107248` (in Chrome on macOS).  So bitwise operations that result in large integers in JS won't give the result you expect, unless you are specifically counting on the overflow behaviour.

Comment: JavaScript will convert bitshift operands and results other than BigInts to 32bit integers: https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-numeric-types-number-leftShift

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

First, your parentheses are completely different your Python and Javascript code. The meaning of the two expressions is different, so it is expected that the result would be different. I don't have any way of knowing which version you actually want, but make sure the order of operations matches.
Second, Javascript numbers are all floating point, but the bitwise operators take a 32 bit integer version of the operands (see [here](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/javascript-the-definitive/0596000480/ch05s08.html#:%7E:text=Despite%20the%20fact%20that%20all,the%20equivalent%20floating%2Dpoint%20representation.)). Your expressions create some pretty large numbers outside the range of a 32 bit integer, so you get overflow. Python, on the other hand, allows arbitrarily large numbers, so overflow isn't an issue there.